# How to write regex rule for div with data tag

Tags: php, regex

How do I grab data-src value with Regex in PHP for data-scale=small only ?

```
<div data-src="http://exampleurl.com/image_url_s.jpg" data-scale="small"></div>
<div data-src="http://exampleurl.com/image_url_b.jpg" data-scale="big"></div>
```

Comment: You don't! Use HTML parser!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using regex, make effective use of [**DOM**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and **XPath** to do this for you.

```
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML('
     <div data-src="http://exampleurl.com/image_url_a.jpg" data-scale="small"></div>
     <div data-src="http://exampleurl.com/image_url_b.jpg" data-scale="small"></div>
     <div data-src="http://exampleurl.com/image_url_c.jpg" data-scale="big"></div>
     <div data-src="http://exampleurl.com/image_url_d.jpg" data-scale="big"></div>
');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//div[@data-scale="small"]');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
   echo $node->getAttribute('data-src'), "\n";
}
```

Output

```
http://exampleurl.com/image_url_a.jpg
http://exampleurl.com/image_url_b.jpg
```